# .NET Core ApiController methods not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have used scaffolding to create an API controller.
This is the test method I have added in there:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult VerifyIsLoggedIn()
        {
            Dictionary<string, bool> result = new Dictionary<string, bool> { { "Authenticated", true} };
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

My Program.cs looks like so:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

I run the app, get the login screen, manage to log in successfully, but then when I go to the URL below, I get an error stating "No webpage was found for the web address:"

https://localhost:12345/api/Authentication/VerifyIsLoggedIn

Seems like I have to make some changes to Program.cs, but everything I have tried hasn't been of any success. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Shown URL does not match the route template for the shown controller action

Comment: @Nkosi how so? Please explain. I'm a bit blurry in this space

Comment: Are you making a POST call to the authentication method? Because it is marked as POST in your code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried making it Get, and then allowing [AllowAnonymous] but it is never called, at least with the format URL I have specified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shown URL

```
https://localhost:12345/api/Authentication/VerifyIsLoggedIn
```

does not match the attribute route template for the shown controller action (see comments in code)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase {    
    //POST api/Authentication
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult VerifyIsLoggedIn() {
        var result = new { Authenticated = true };
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Also if you try to view the URL in a browser it will default to HTTP GET while the controller can only serve HTTP POST requests.

You would need to update the HTTP Verb used and the route template

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase {    
    //GET api/Authentication/VerifyIsLoggedIn
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult VerifyIsLoggedIn() {
        var result = new { Authenticated = true };
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: okay, in the first example you commented this `//POST api/Authentication`. Does that mean if I navigate to `https://localhost:12345/api/Authentication` without the action then that method will be called? Assuming ofcoz that it is a post request.

Comment: Yes if you were to POST to `api/Authentication` it should hit that action.

Comment: Well I'll be damned, that worked. Good stuff. Will go through those references when I get a chance. Sounds like I have a bit to learn on routing.

Answer (score 0):

Am facing the same issue in my case when creating new API project uncheck the configure for HTTPS box.
Issue resolved in my case